# Django: Subtract the time from two datetime objects

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I need to subtract two times and get the number of minutes between them to the nearest minutes. For the scheduled_time, it has become in string and im not able to convert it back to time

```
present_time = timezone.now().time()
print(present_time) //output is -> 10:36:01.847822
scheduled_time = datetime.strftime(test.scheduled_date_time, '%H:%M:%S') //output is -> 10:20:52 in string format
print(scheduled_time)
```

How do I subtract both and get the result to the nearest minutes? :(

Comment: You just converted datetime to str by strftime, so why can’t you use that time instance ti substract.

Comment: @MohamedElKalioby, it cant as it has become a string

Comment: Why did you set it as string and if it is a string, you can covert it back to datetime using ‘strptime’ function

Comment: @MohamedElKalioby, it wasn't working. Can you please help me to code it the right way?

Comment: What is type of test.scheduled_time?

Comment: test.scheduled_date_time is a datetime field in the Test Model which stores the date and time for which the test is scheduled for

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233926/discussion-between-alpha-and-mohamed-elkalioby).

Answer (score 0):

Here you go,

```
time_delta = (present_time - test.scheduled_time).total_seconds() % 60
```

Comment: getting the error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'str'

Comment: Chexk updated answer, timedelta works on two instances of datetime

Comment: i think there is a confusion on variable names. Can you check?